# Live Search on Grid --ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJs, and i am playing around to build logic to perform "live search" on Grid columns.

From the code below i am able to populate data into the grid but cannot make live search functionality. i am not sure where i am missing the logic.

```
    Ext.define('abc.view.EmployeePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.EmployeePanel',
    requires: [
        'Ext.tab.Panel',
        'Ext.form.*'],
          constructor: function () {
         this.callParent(arguments);
        },

        this. employeePopUPGridStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [
                {
                    name: 'empid',
                    type: 'number'
                },
                {
                    name: 'fname',
                    type: 'string'
                },
                {
                    name: 'lname',
                    type: 'string'
                },

            ],

        });

      this.employeePopUPGridStore.loadData(localAr, false);
        this.down('#addempgrid').bindStore(this.employeePopUPGridStore);
        this.down('#addempgrid').getView().refresh(); 
    },
    items: [{
           xtype:'textfield',
             name:'search',
             itemId:'search',
             emptyText:'Search by First Name / Last Name',
             listeners: {
            onTextFieldChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts){
              var grid = field.down('addempgrid');
              grid.store.clearFilter();
               if (newValue) {
                  var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(newValue), "i");
                  grid.store.filter({
                      filterFn: function(item) {
                          return matcher.test(item.get('empid')) ||
                              matcher.test(item.get('fname')) ||
                             matcher.test(item.get('job'));
                      }
                  });
              }
          }
         }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            itemId: 'addempgrid',
            autoHeight: true,
            columns: [

                {
                    header: "Employee ID",
                    flex: 1,
                    dataIndex: 'empid',

                },
                {
                    header: "Full Name",
                    flex: 3,
                    dataIndex: 'fname'
                },
                {
                    header: "LastName",
                    flex: 1,
                    dataIndex: 'lname'
                },


            ]

        }
    ] }
});
```

Any help around is much appreciated.

Comment: There's no method `onTextFieldChange`, you just made that up. You need to listen to the text field change event (probably also want to look at the buffer option).

Comment: Thanks for quick response, i tired with listener but still no luck, BTW what is buffer option could you please throw some light... :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this way once..

```
  {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    itemId: 'searchBar',
                    cls: 'search-bar',
                    width: 230,
                    margin: '0 0 0 10',
                    listeners: {
                        buffer: 250,
                        scope: this,
                        change: function (field, newVal) {
                      var grid = field.down('addempgrid');
                         grid.store.clearFilter();
                if (newValue) {
                      var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(newValue), "i");
                       grid.store.filter({
                        filterFn: function(item) {
                           return matcher.test(item.get('empid')) ||
                           matcher.test(item.get('fname')) ||
                           matcher.test(item.get('job'));

                         }
                     });
                    }

                }
            }
          }
```

Hope it helps you